# How do I make this button quit the parent window in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've tried for 2 days to get this to work with no luck. I've tried all the methods found on related questions - destroy, quit, sys.exit... nothing's working. The issue is that my code seems to be written in a slightly different way than tkinter code is usually written on SO, because I'm using a separate class for each window, on top of the main class. I'm therefore having difficulty seeing where the "root" variable used in similar questions corresponds to my code (the common suggestion is "command=root.quit" or similar). However, I'm sure the structure of the code is fine (the app runs fine) as I copied the basic framework from sentdex's "Multiple Windows/Frames in Tkinter GUI with Python" video.

The code is as follows, with irrelevant parts of "StartPage" removed. There is also "PageOne" and "PageTwo", not included, which are very similar to StartPage. I will need the same button on these two pages.

The for loop and show_frame method in the main class is used for switching between the frames via buttons. This all works fine.

```
class testApp(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    container = tk.Frame(self)

    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)


    self.frames = {}

    for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

        frame = F(container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()





class StartPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    ...

    confirmFrame = tk.Frame(self)
    confirmFrame.pack()

    ... 

    self.buttonNo = tk.Button(confirmFrame, text="No, quit the program",
                        command=????)
    self.buttonNo.pack()

app = testApp()
app.mainloop()
```

For full clarity then, the button "buttonNo" in StartPage needs to quit the entire program, via some command which I cannot figure out.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Maybe `sys.exit()`?

Comment: @Goyo Thanks - I've tried that, the program runs, but the button just does nothing when clicked.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of 2 ways:

To obtain the toplevel (your window) use `self.winfo_toplevel()`, so `self.winfo_toplevel().quit()`  should end your application.

Less nice is using `self._root().quit()` which uses a private function (see the leading underscore on _root), so may be changed without warning.

Comment: `self.winfo_toplevel().quit()`, not `self.winfo_toplevel.quit()`

Comment: @BrianOakley I was convinced it was a data attribute, but of course you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Your `testApp` inherits from tk.Tk, so it becomes the root. And it gets passed as the `controller` arg, so your frames can use that name to access it. Here's a quick demo derived from your code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class testApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        confirmFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        confirmFrame.pack()

        self.buttonNo = tk.Button(confirmFrame, text="No, quit the program",
                            command=controller.quit)
        self.buttonNo.pack()

app = testApp()
app.mainloop()
```

---

BTW, it makes it a lot easier for us to help you if you post a MCVE. Otherwise we need to spend time figuring out what we need to add & remove from your code before we can even run it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried controller.quit but unfortunately this didn't work. "Your testApp inherits from tk.Tk, so it becomes the root. And it gets passed as the controller arg, so your frames can use that name to access it." This was very helpful though thank you. I did think I posted an example that would work but clearly not. Will make sure next time,  thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Just to clarify on how controller.quit didn't work - the program ran, but the button did nothing when clicked.

Comment: @SeanW Sorry, I don't understand. The code I posted exits the program when the button is clicked. I tested it on Python 3.6.0 and 2.6.6

Comment: That's strange as another user posted that sys.exit worked for him when it didn't for me - and the same problem happened, the button did nothing when clicked. I'm using 3.6 and I tried it in both IDLE and spyder.

Comment: @SeanW I don't know about spyder, but running Tkinter stuff inside IDLE can be flaky because IDLE is itself a Tkinter program.

Comment: Ah. Appreciate the heads up.